# Background image getting cropped instead fitting in element on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have code to show a background image in a card header like below:

```
<div class="card-heading"></div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.card-1 .card-heading {
  background: url("../images/bg-head-02.jpg") center center/cover no-repeat;
  padding-top: 210px;
}
```

In desktop its looking fine like this:

[image]

But in mobile device its getting cut off like below:

[image]

How can I fix my code so that it also fits in mobile.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting close votes for lacking debugging details - everything we need to see the problem is in the question!

Comment: @FluffyKitten Overzealousness? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem: You are using the `cover` value for the `background-size` property**. This means that the image will be resized to fit either the height or width of the available space, and any "extra" image will be cropped. In your case, the image is being made big enough to fit into the height of your element, which makes it too wide to fit so the width is getting cropped.

**Note that using a separate `background-size: cover;` CSS will not change this behaviour** - it behaves the same way as when it is included in the `background` shorthand. You can see this in the working examples below.

---

**Option 1: background-size: contain** If you want the image to fit fully into the space, you can use `contain`- *however note that this will add empty space* above and/or below the image because the aspect ratio will no longer match the image itself.

---

**Solution - Option 2: Make the element the correct aspect ratio for the image**.
You can use `%` padding instead of fixed padding.
To calculate the correct percentage use: `image_height / image_width` e.g. in the example here : `210/1200` = `17.5%`

---

**Compare all of these options in the example below:**

```css
.card-heading {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1200x210") center center/cover no-repeat;
  padding-top: 210px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.card-heading-cover {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1200x210") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 210px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.card-heading-contain {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1200x210") center center/contain no-repeat;
  padding-top: 210px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.card-heading-responsive {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1200x210") center center/cover no-repeat;
  padding-top: 17.5%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Background: cover</strong> (like your example) - image is cropped</p>
<div class="card-heading"></div>

<p><strong>Background-size: cover</strong> - image is <i>still</i> getting cropped:</p>
<div class="card-heading-cover"></div>

<p><strong>Background-size: contain</strong> - note the extra space</p>
<div class="card-heading-contain"></div>

<p><strong>% padding</strong> - resizes to fit the image aspect ratio</p>
<div class="card-heading-responsive"></div>
```